# Is it possible to migrate a croogo cms website posts to drupal?

Tags: drupal, cakephp, content-management-system, data-migration

My client has a website built with croogo cms , nothing special just a blog. I want to convert it to drupal by their permission but i dont know croogo. Is there any way to migrate croogo posts to drupal? or should i manually entry them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only a few  posts then I would say manually enter them. Anything more than a 50 posts should be automated in my opinion.

check out http://drupal.org/project/migrate maybe this cane help you.

Otherwise use json as an output from croogo and then use drush to import it into drupal.

Comment: thanks for the response, however my problem was solved by another method. I just found that my client used to be on joomla. I have the joomlaDB and there is a drupal module for joomla to drupal migration it was as easy as a pie